# F3 Does Not Respond in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I press the Function key and F3, and it shows the debug screen. However, when I try to toggle something like "advanced tooltips" (Fn+F3+H), it doesn't work at all. I have a 2017 Dell Inspiron, and there is no way to rebind the function of F3 to any other key. Does someone have a way to fix this?

Comment: don't hold Fn and try again

Answer (score 2):

You can always try reversing the function of the FN key (using FN + F3 for the multimedia option instead of the actual F3 function).

To do this you have to go into your BIOS settings.

Firstly, if you don't know how to go into BIOS you can hold down the shift key while clicking the reboot option on Windows 10.

This will get you into the advanced startup menu.

[image]

From there click troubleshoot and then UEFI Settings.

From the UEFI settings go to the Advanced TAB

From there you can  change the function of the F* keys.

Choose Function key and you are good to go.

If this doesn't work, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief, the function key is usually a toggle. So if you press <kbd>FN</kbd> and then <kbd>F3</kbd>, function is already selected, so all you have to do is <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.